# Conversation with a superior intelligence

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, story, steganography

> I have created an unprecedented level of artificial intelligence here in my mother's basement. Its performance is far superior to an average human brain, to the point that it almost rivals my own. Finally I can have actual intelligent discussions with someone! I'm feeling all excited. Now to turn it on for the first time.
>
> *(click)*
>
> Hello, bot!
>
> ```
> lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
> conectetur adipiscing eli — —
> ```
>
> What the? You're supposed to...
>
> ```
> sed do eismod temor incdidunt
> ut labore et olore agna aliqua — —
> ```
>
> ...be able to form coherent, intelligible sentences. What is this?
>
> ```
> ut nim ad minim venim quis nosrud
> exercitation ullamco laoris nisi — —
> ```
>
> Okay, off you go. *(click)* Time to check all the parameters once again. It's not *impossible* that I have made a mistake somewhere (although it *is* unheard of). Let's see...
>
> Everything seems to be in order. All the parameters are correct. The power source is working. The intelligence-o-meter is showing a value of 999, as it should.
>
> Let's try this again. Turn this back on...
>
> *(click)*
>
> Hello, bot!
>
> ```
> ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat
> duis aute irue dolor in reprehenderit — —
> ```
>
> No no no no NO. You're supposed to be able to speak!
>
> ```
> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore
> eu fugit nulla paratur excepteur sit — —
> ```
>
> English, bot, ENGLISH! Do you speak it?
>
> ```
> occaecat cupidatat non proident sunt in cupa
> qui officia deserunt mlit anim id est laborum — —
> ```
>
> **click** Sigh. Back to the drawing board, I guess. I was sure I had finally created a brain that matches my vast intelligence. One that I could have intelligent conversations with...
>
> Mother! What's taking so long with those meatballs?

What is up with the bot?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bot says:

> Stupid  Meatbrain LOL

The message is hidden in:

> https://www.lipsum.com/
>  The message is the letters that are missing from the Lorem Ipsum